# Lifreay 6.1 : How to disable /c/portal/login url from public web site

Tags: liferay, liferay-6

I am using Liferay 6.1.
For public web site example. www.sitename.com
If I enter www.sitename.com/c/portal/login , it is redirected to login

i want to disable this.

how is it possible ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Try to set this property in your portal-ext.properties:

```
auth.login.disabled=true
```

Comment: Will this also disable our local server url example public site: www.example.com/c/portal/login and local server www.example.com:8080/c/portal/login ??

Comment: Yes, if you set that property and try to go /c/portal/login, a warning message appears. In order to change this message, there are a few methods, the simplest one is to build a hook plugin and override /html/portal/login_disabled.jsp.